# Install EF 4.4.0.0

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, nuget

Currently I have Entity Framework 5.0 installed in Visual Studio 2012. For some reason the project only is supported by EF 4.4.0.0.

So I installed EF 4.4.0.0 but I have the error in the Nuget command line:

> PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 4.4.0.0
>   Install-Package : Unable to find version '4.4.0.0' of package 'EntityFramework'.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 4.4.0.0
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

PM>

Comment: Version 4.4.0 doesn't exists http://www.nuget.org/packages/entityframework

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The versioning headache you are seeing is due to differences in what EF can support depending on what version of the .NET run time your app is targeting.

If you are targeting .NET 4 and install EF 5, the assembly version will be 4.4

If you are targeting .NET 4.5 and install EF 5, the assembly version will be 5.0

This is because things such as DBGeography only can work if .NET 4.5 is present.

Just install EF 5 proper and the NuGet package will figure this out and give you the proper version.

Comment: Should I remove the current EF manually or Nuget will delete it when installing?

Comment: Honestly, if you have an entity framework reference in your project that says 4.4 you're probably already done and don't need to do anything if this is a .NET 4 project. If this is a .NET 4.5 and it's a 4.4 EF DLL, I'd remove it and then re-add EF 5 from NuGet.

Answer (score 8):

tl;tr
When you need assembly version 4.4.0.0 on .NET 4.0, just type into Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 6):

OK, so the deal here is that EF 5 is only supported by .net 4.5 projects (ie no .net 4). However if you have a .NET 4 project and try to install EF 5 what they do is give you another binary (called EF 4.4) which runs with .NET 4.

This means all you need to do is install the EF 5 package and you will get the correct (4.4) version of EF.

For a little more info from the EF team see http://brice-lambson.blogspot.ca/2012/10/unicorn-myths-debunked-entity-framework.html